# Filter WordPress Posts with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've been following this tutorial: http://pixelers.net/filter-wordpress-posts-by-category-with-ajax/. and working.

I want to create a filter based on the popular and recent post. For popular post based on a lot of the post being viewed.

For "Recent" bring up the last post. For "Popular" only display post based on the number of most viewed.

[image]

**index.php**

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <ul class="post-filters">
        <li><a href="">Recent</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Popular</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<main id="main" class="content site-main">
    <?php $query_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args ); 
    ?>
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'grid' ); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</main>
```

**ajax.php**

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
var $mainContent = $( '#main' ),
    $cat_links = $( '.post-filters li a' );

    $cat_links.on( 'click', function ( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $el = $(this);
        var value = $el.attr( "href" );
        $mainContent.animate({opacity: "0.7"}); 
        $mainContent.load(value + " #main", function(){
            $mainContent.animate({opacity: "1"});

        }); 
    }); 
});
```

How can I make a link recent and popular it can Clicked and filter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make your HTML Structure like this .. Keep its inner HTML blank for first time.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <ul class="post-filters">
        <li><a href="" id="recent_posts">Recent</a></li>
        <li><a href="" id="latest_posts">Popular</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<main id="main" class="content site-main">

</main>
```

Create onclick events in footer.php of the active theme

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( "#recent_posts" ).click(function() {
  var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
      $.post(
          ajaxurl, 
          {
              'action'  :   'fetch_posts',
              'fetch' :   'recent_posts',
          }, 
          function(output){
            $('#main').html(output);
          });
});

$( "#latest_posts" ).click(function() {
  var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
      $.post(
          ajaxurl, 
          {
              'action'  :   'fetch_posts',
              'fetch' :   'latest_posts',
          }, 
          function(output){

          });
});


</script>
```

Put the below code to start coding in the functions.php of active theme

```
add_action('wp_ajax_fetch_posts', 'fetch_posts');

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_fetch_posts', 'fetch_posts');


function import_map_landing() {
    if($_REQUEST['fetch'] == 'latest_posts'){
        $query_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            );
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args ); 

        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
             while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                $return_str.= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                $return_str.=//paste the content of content-grid template here 
                $return_str.='</div>';
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
            else :
                $return_str.= 'No posts found'
        endif;
    } 
    if($_REQUEST['fetch'] == 'recent_posts'){
        //do the code for recent posts here 
        //need to be concatinated in $return_str 
    }

    echo $return_str;
    die;
}
?>
```

We are concatinating all the output (php code and HTML) in the $return_str and it is echoed at the end . so please dont forget to concatinate .

> Templates part needs to be pasted here not to be included

Like this `<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'grid' ); ?>` needs to be replaced with the code inside this page.

Also at the start of the page we can fire the `onclick` event `onload()` to get the data on page load

For EG

```
$( body ).load(function() {
   var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
          $.post(
              ajaxurl, 
              {
                  'action'  :   'fetch_posts',
                  'fetch' :   'recent_posts',
              }, 
              function(output){
                $('#main').html(output);
              });
});
```

I have called the recent_posts funtion on page load , you can switch to latest_posts as per your choice

Comment: Thank you @Prakash Rao,

another quoestion, where I put 

$( body ).load(function() {
........
});

I've placed it before the closing of the head, and it didn't work.

Comment: put it in footer.php (footer.php must load in the file which is having the tan for latest and Recent posts)

Comment: Thank you very much @Prakash Rao.

The problem is body is not defined, May I know why?

Sorry, I'm still a beginner, and this wordpress theme is a theme that I modified from another theme :)

Comment: Put body in single quotes as $('body')

Comment: Still not working, the #main not load. And the content not appear.